# How do I send SSIS log information to a text box when executing a package from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I have a button that, when clicked, will execute an SSIS package at a location specified by the user.  This functionality works fine, but what I am particularly interested in is relaying information about package execution back to the user in the UI.

**Is it possible to write the log messages to a textbox OR somehow display the package execution progress window to the user?**

By "Package Execution Progress" window I mean this window:
[image: SSIS Package Execution Progress window]

I am aware that the `Package.Execute()` contains an [IDTSLogging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtslogging.aspx) parameter, but I do not know if that is what I need because I haven't been able to find an applicable code example and I am very new to C#.  Most of the code examples I've seen that execute an SSIS package do not include any parameters in the Execute method.

I do not want to write information to a separate log file, as a matter of personal preference.  I considered writing log output to a file (I have a working example of this I could use) and then reading the contents of that file into the textbox using the `File.ReadAllText` method, but that seems highly inefficient.  If need be, this may work as a last resort.

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: I'm guessing you either need to subscribe to events when you run the package, or you need to actually put event handlers inside your package and push events out

Answer (score 1):

See this [Example](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/01/call-ssis-2012-package-within-net.html), downside is that the log is available after the package is ready.
[image]